# How to check if string is of certain format with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

Using js how would I check if a string is of a number of similar but slightly different.

```
'2016-01-19:*
'2015-11-05:350'
'2015-11-05:3+'
'2015-11-05:3-'
'2015-11-05:3>=<=14'
```

Above are all the different types of accepted strings. Each of the numbers after the colon can be any length. '2015-11-05:3>=<=7' and '2015-11-05:15693>=<=180999' are both accepted.

I'm sure I'll have to use regex, but not sure how.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [`\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:.*`](https://www.debuggex.com/r/v9h5vC7uA5o28CWY)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this might help

```js
/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:.*/.test("2016-01-19:*")
```

Comment: Might want to tweak that to be `/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}:.*/.test("2016-01-19:*")` Adding the caret at the beginning ensures that the string begins with that pattern, and there's no preceding characters

Comment: how do I apply that into an if statement?